# How to prevent a callback in the Twitter stream from firing with each new tweet?

Tags: node.js, twitter, asynchronous, callback, socket.io

My app sifts through the Twitter stream for matching strings. When it finds a match, it is supposed to increment a counter and emit the new count to the client via socket.io. Unfortuntely, socket.io is emitting with every tweet, not every match. It is emitting exponentially more often than necessary, causing browser issues. How can I prevent the callback from getting called with each new event in the Twitter stream?

Here is my code for the twitter stream:

```
// Compares watchList (NYT Keywords) to Twitter stream, counts every mention
exports.keywordStream = function(callback) {
  exports.initializeFeed().then(function(watchList) {

  // enter the stream
    t.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchKeywords }, function(stream) {

    // read twitter firehose ('data') for incoming tweets.
      stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        var tweetText = tweet.text.toLowerCase();

        // compare the text of each tweet to each NYT keyword in the watchList
        _.each(watchKeywords, function(e) {

          // if the keyword exists in the tweet, += 1
          if (tweetText.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            watchList.keywords[e] += 1;
            watchList.total += 1;
          }

        });
        callback(watchList);
      });
    });
  });
 };
```

Here is my code in app.js. I want this to emit whenever there is a matching tweet.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // console.log("client connected");
});

firehose.keywordStream(function(watchList) {
  // STREAMING . . .
  setInterval(function() {
    io.sockets.emit('watchUpdate', {'watchList': watchList});
  }, 1000/60);
});
```

And here is just a snippet from my views file:

```
<script>
 var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
 console.log('hello world')
   socket.on('watchUpdate', function(data) {
   console.log('chirp')
```

After about 20 seconds, my browser is locked down. It looks something like this:

[image]

After writing this question, I realized that the callback function which handles the updated watchList is located inside the twitter stream. The callback appears to be called with each tweet, whether the tweet hits the IF statement or not. If I put the callback inside the IF statement, the callback still gets called with every tweet.

Cheers for any insights, hints or comments on the nature of callbacks in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was nesting emits in a setInterval. The setInterval was stacking with each callback. If you remove the setInterval(), io.sockets.emit will perform as expected.

```
// app.js
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // console.log("client connected");
});

firehose.keywordStream(function(watchList) {
  io.sockets.emit('watchUpdate', {'watchList': watchList});
});
```

The final touch is to place my callback within the IF statement, to ensure it fires only on a matching keyword.

```
 // twitter firehose
 exports.keywordStream = function(callback) {
   exports.initializeFeed().then(function(watchList) {

     // enter the stream
     t.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchKeywords }, function(stream) {

       // read twitter firehose ('data') for incoming tweets.
       stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
         var tweetText = tweet.text.toLowerCase();

         // compare the text of each tweet to each NYT keyword in the watchList
         _.each(watchKeywords, function(e) {

           // if the keyword exists in the tweet, += 1
           if (tweetText.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
             watchList.keywords[e] += 1;
             watchList.total += 1;
             callback(watchList);
           }
         });
       });
     });
   });
 };
```

With these two tweaks in place, the browser receives real-time updates for matching tweets.